# I cant upload full data from excel to database using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying for upload data from excel sheet to database using php. I cant upload full data from excel sheet to database.I can upload  only 10 data from excel to database.My excel sheet contain 20 data.But only upload 10 numbers.I refered these http://www.discussdesk.com/import-excel-file-data-in-mysql-database-using-PHP.htm.

My code is given below.

```
   main Page

  <input type="button" name="submit"  onClick="file_up()"/>
  <srcipt>
  function file_up()
  {
      var file=$('#file').val();
     var cell=$('#cell').val();
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'ajx_upload.php',
     data:'file='+file + '&cell=' + cell,
     success: function(msg)
      { 
      $("#upload_show").html(msg);
      }
  });

  }
 </script>

   ajx_upload.php


    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $uploadedStatus = 0;
    $cell=$_POST['cell'];
    $file1=$_POST['file'];
    $file1 = str_replace("\\", "\\", $file1);
    $file1 = explode("\\",$file1);
    $file=$file1[2];

   if (file_exists($file)) {
    unlink($file);
    }
  $storagename = "discussdesk.xlsx";
  move_uploaded_file($file,  $storagename);
  $uploadedStatus = 1;
   //

 if($uploadedStatus==1)
  {
     define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); // set database host
     define ("DB_USER", "root"); // set database user
     define ("DB_PASS",""); // set database password
     define ("DB_NAME","excel"); // set database name

     $link = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or 
     die("Couldn't make       connection.");
     $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

     $databasetable = "first";

     set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
     include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    // This is the file path to be uploaded.
       $inputFileName = 'discussdesk.xlsx'; 

     try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.
     pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
     }


     $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
     $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  
       // Here get total count of row in that        Excel sheet
      //print_r($allDataInSheet);
    for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
     {
       $userName = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
       $userMobile = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
       $query = "SELECT name FROM first WHERE name = '".$userName."'
        and email =         '".$userMobile."'";
       $sql = mysql_query($query);
       $recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
       $existName = $recResult["name"];
       if($existName=="") 
        {
              $insertTable= mysql_query("insert into 
              first (name, email)  values('".$userName."', '".$userMobile."');");
        } 
       }
       ?>
```

Comment: Create one sql query including all the inserts, not xx separate sql insert queries.

Comment: in these array   $allDataInSheet contain  only  10 elements.